# Change CSV delimiter in ServiceStack.Text.CsvSerializer

Tags: c#, csv, servicestack, servicestack-text

If possible, how can I change the delimiter from comma to semicolon when using ServiceStack.Text.CsvSerializer?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can control this by setting

```
 ServiceStack.Text.CsvConfig.ItemSeperatorString = ";";
```

From the [version 3.9.14 Release Notes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/wiki/Release-Notes):

> - CsvConfig.ItemSeperatorString - Enables configuration of the separator between items in a csv file (ie | or ; rather than ,)
> - CsvConfig.ItemDelimiterString - Enables configuration of the delimiter for an item that needs to be escaped in a csv file (ie | rather than ")
> - CsvConfig.RowSeparatorString - Enables configuration of the delimiter for a row of items in a csv file (ie | \r\n)

Note that the setting is [thread static](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Text/CsvConfig.cs).  (Note also the misspelling.)